# Create mysql trigger to update another table's column based on average of a column on this table

Tags: php, mysql

Just went through a bit of documentation of mysql triggers and trying to create a trigger. 
Attached here is a picture of my table structures. I have two tables.. [image]

My problem is :
I want to update the progress of a parent task in the `tasks` table, whenever one of its subtask's progress is updated in the 
`subtasks` table.

for example, the `Complete Fees Module` has two subtasks: 'Read the structure' and 'task2'. 
So value of task_progress of this task in the 'tasks' table should be average progress of the subtasks.
i.e. (23 + 25) / 2;

The below syntax is wrong I know...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_progress
AFTER INSERT ON `task_status` FOR EACH ROW
begin
   DECLARE avg_progress integer;

   @avg_prog = sum of this query...
   {
   select subtask_progress from subtasks where task = NEW.task
   }

       UPDATE tasks
       SET task_progress = @avg_progress
       WHERE subtasks.task = tasks.task

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Am I on the right track? Would appreciate if someone suggests an actual working trigger?

Comment: First, the task column in subtasks should be the ID from the tasks table. Second, the first query should look like this: `select AVG(subtask_progress) AS subtask_progress from subtasks where task = NEW.task`

Comment: @CptMisery thanks for the suggestion in the table structure. I know having ID as a reference to another table's row is a better practice, but this is just an experiment...